# Summing across a row in Pandas DataFrame and adding a Total column yields 0.0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to sum all cells (logged working time, in seconds--I can handle the reformatting to HH:MM later when the summing is complete) in a pandas dataframe row to create a "total_hours" column.

- The table has an id column, so my code (hopefully) avoids including the first column in the summing.
- the rows include int, str, and list values. I used the "numeric_only=True" parameter to avoid including non-ints.
- I read somewhere transposing might help. It didn't.
- Screenshot of the table attached: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqTzr.png

My code:

```
def final_output(df):
    df =  pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(list(df['daily_logs']))],axis=1).drop(columns='daily_logs')
    df['total_hours'] = df.iloc[:,1:].sum(axis=1,numeric_only = True) #this is the part that isn't working as intended.
    return df

df_results = final_output(df)
df_results
```

The data and output are below. The df without "total_hours" is the input. The output looks fine, except the "total_hours" should actually represent a sum of all the integers in the row, and not yield 0.0.

|  | id | name | 2023-11-28 | 2023-11-29 | 2023-11-30 | 2023-12-01 | 2023-12-02 | 2023-12-03 | 2023-12-04 | 2023-12-05 | total_hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 514 | alexis | No hours logged | No hours logged | No hours logged | No hours logged | No hours logged | No hours logged | No hours logged | No hours logged | 0.0 |
| 1 | 2414 | donald | 29160 | 29160 | 28860 | 28620 | [10:02, Odd number: missing entry] | No hours logged | No hours logged | 28860 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 3225 | mackenzie | 28500 | 28620 | 28560 | 28620 | 28980 | No hours logged | No hours logged | 28740 | 0.0 |
| 3 | 3434 | louisa | 25380 | 18840 | 26040 | No hours logged | 25560 | No hours logged | No hours logged | 24900 | 0.0 |
| 4 | 3864 | olga | 15600 | 19080 | 14400 | 13800 | 5220 | 17820 | No hours logged | 14400 | 0.0 |
| 5 | 4716 | rick | 30180 | 28800 | 28740 | 28620 | 28680 | No hours logged | No hours logged | 28680 | 0.0 |
| 6 | 5793 | roberta | 29220 | 29220 | 29460 | 29280 | 29340 | No hours logged | No hours logged | 29040 | 0.0 |

Comment: welcome to SO, read following notice before ask : [mre] , [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Please explain better what you are trying to do. Please add sample of data and expected output

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and the feedback. Edited the post with additional details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation of [`df.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html), the parameter `numeric_only` is used to:

> [i]nclude only float, int, boolean columns.

All the columns you are selecting contain at least one string, hence all of them are excluded from the calculation, leading to the sum of an empty Series (default: `0`) for each row.

What you are trying to do, can be achieved by first applying [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) to each of the columns selected, with the `errors` parameter set to `coerce`, causing invalid parsing to result in `NaN`.

```py
# N.B. start at `df.iloc[:, 2:]`, not `1:`; "id" is the first column

df['total_hours'] = (
    df.iloc[:, 2:]
      .apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
      .sum(axis=1)
)

df['total_hours']

0         0.0
1    144660.0
2    172020.0
3    120720.0
4    100320.0
5    173700.0
6    175560.0
Name: total_hours, dtype: float64
```

To adjust the formatting, you could use [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```py
pd.to_timedelta(df['total_hours'], unit='s')

0   0 days 00:00:00
1   1 days 16:11:00
2   1 days 23:47:00
3   1 days 09:32:00
4   1 days 03:52:00
5   2 days 00:15:00
6   2 days 00:46:00
Name: total_hours, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

**Data used**

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'id': {0: 514, 1: 2414, 2: 3225, 3: 3434, 4: 3864, 5: 4716, 6: 5793},
    'name': {0: 'alexis', 1: 'donald', 2: 'mackenzie', 3: 'louisa', 4: 'olga', 5: 'rick', 6: 'roberta'},
    '2023-11-28': {0: 'No hours logged', 1: '29160', 2: '28500', 3: '25380', 4: '15600', 5: '30180', 6: '29220'},
    '2023-11-29': {0: 'No hours logged', 1: '29160', 2: '28620', 3: '18840', 4: '19080', 5: '28800', 6: '29220'},
    '2023-11-30': {0: 'No hours logged', 1: '28860', 2: '28560', 3: '26040', 4: '14400', 5: '28740', 6: '29460'},
    '2023-12-01': {0: 'No hours logged', 1: '28620', 2: '28620', 3: 'No hours logged', 4: '13800', 5: '28620', 6: '29280'},
    '2023-12-02': {0: 'No hours logged', 1: '[10:02, Odd number: missing entry]', 2: '28980', 3: '25560', 4: '5220', 5: '28680', 6: '29340'},
    '2023-12-03': {0: 'No hours logged', 1: 'No hours logged', 2: 'No hours logged', 3: 'No hours logged', 4: '17820', 5: 'No hours logged', 6: 'No hours logged'},
    '2023-12-04': {0: 'No hours logged', 1: 'No hours logged', 2: 'No hours logged', 3: 'No hours logged', 4: 'No hours logged', 5: 'No hours logged', 6: 'No hours logged'},
    '2023-12-05': {0: 'No hours logged', 1: '28860', 2: '28740', 3: '24900', 4: '14400', 5: '28680', 6: '29040'},
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```